# Inconvertible types; can not cast ArrayList<Parcelable> to List<>

Tags: android, arraylist

I am not able to send List because of inconvertible type ArrayList vs List.

To send `List<ItemNb> nbList`:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("nbList", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) nbList);
```

To get `List<ItemNb> nbList`:

```
List<ItemNb> nbList = (List<ItemNb>) getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("nbList");
```

How to convert `ArrayList<android.os.Parcelable>` to `List<ItemNb>`. Or is there any better approach to send list of objects via intent.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. can you pls explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your object class implement Parcelable..

Create list and send as below

```
List<Object> prints = new ArrayList<>();
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) prints);
```

Get value in another class as:

```
    List<Print> prints2 = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("");
```

Comment: removing typecast (List) works. It came out of because of the link I was referring used this type cast.